# SetFilePointer() on another's process file handle fails

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, 64-bit

I'm making a GUI for a third party untouchable console executable. This executable reads an input file, processes the data and generates an output file. As the process can take a long time I need to monitor the progress.

What I want to do is to locate the console executable process id (done), with the process id retrieve the list of files opened by the process (done) and then, once the input file is identified and it's handle is retreived (done), I want to call SetFilePointer(handle, 0, currentPosition) so it tells me what ammount of file has been already read. Then, (read/totalSize) will give me the progress of the process.

THE PROBLEM is that invoking SetFilePointer() always returns 0xFFFFFFFF (fail) and GetLastError() returns 6 (invalid handle). Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handles belong to the owning process and can only be operated on by the owning process. If you want to modify a handle in another process you'll need to inject code into that process, or use `DuplicateHandle`.

Comment: Would it be possible to use DuplicateHandle() as a workaround for this? I mean, once I have the original file handle, I duplicate it and call SetFilePointer() on the duplicated one.

Comment: Yes I think that will work. Sorry I forgot about that originally. I think you might potentially have issues with thread-safety if both processes access the file pointer at the same time. I know that your modification is benign but I wonder what happens if you were to read the file pointer at exactly the same time as the target app modifies the file.

Comment: It seems to work !!! Yeah, I also wonder what will happen if (when) both processes access the file pointer at once. I suppose I'll have to make intensive testing and see what happens, but that's... another story. Thank you... a beer for my UK friend...